# How do I get a SafeTransaction from it's transaction hash?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am trying to execute a SafeTransaction using gnosis sdk (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@safe-global), but I only have it's transaction hash. How do I fetch the safe transaction object using the hash so I can execute it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Safe is independent from Gnosis now, so it is the "Safe{Core} SDK" now :)

This SDK containts the [API KIT](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/api-kit) that allows to retrieve a transaction given its Safe transaction hash. Here there is the documentation covering this:

https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/api-kit#retrieve-the-pending-transactions